# Problema ao executar teste de reconhecimento facial com Python - OpenCV

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Ao executar o seguinte código de teste:

```
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

detector_face = cv2.CascadeClassifier(r"C:\Users\JokerDTR\Documents\SoftwaresProjeto\ReconhecimentoFacial\protótipo\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
reconhecedor = cv2.face.EigenFaceRecognizer_create()
reconhecedor.read("classificadorEigen.yml")
# reconhecedor = cv2.face.FisherFaceRecognizer_create()
# reconhecedor.read("classificadorFisher.yml")
# reconhecedor = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
# reconhecedor.read("classificadorLBPH.yml")

total_acertos = 0
percentual_acerto = 0.0
total_confianca = 0.0

caminhos = [os.path.join('TESTE', f) for f in os.listdir('TESTE')]
for caminhos_imagem in caminhos:
    imagem_face = Image.open(caminhos_imagem).convert('L')
    imagem_np = np.array(imagem_face, 'uint8')
    faces_detectadas = detector_face.detectMultiScale(imagem_face)
    for (x, y, l, a) in faces_detectadas:
        idprevisto, confianca = reconhecedor.predict(imagemFaceNP)
        idatual = int(os.path.split(caminhos_imagem)[1].split(".")[0].replace("subject", ""))
        print(str(idatual) + " foi classificado como " + str(idprevisto) + " - " + str(confianca))
        if idprevisto == idatual:
            totalAcertos += 1
            totalConfianca += confianca
        cv2.rectangle(imagemFaceNP, (x, y), (x + l, y + a), (0, 0, 255), 2)
        cv2.imshow("Face", imagemFaceNP)
        cv2.waitKey(1000)
percentual_acerto = (total_acertos / 30) * 100
total_confianca = total_confianca / total_acertos
print("Percentual de acerto: " + str(percentual_acerto))
print("Total confiança: " + str(total_confianca))
```

Estou tendo o erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "teste.py", line 22, in <module>
    faces_detectadas = detector_face.detectMultiScale(imagem_face)
TypeError: Expected cv::UMat for argument 'image'
```

Comment: A sua imagem é do tipo `Matrix of the type CV_8U containing an image where objects are detected.`? Ou seja 8-bit unsigned integer (uchar). Em vez de utilizar a biblioteca PIL, use a do OpenCV para abrir e converter a imagem, já que o OpenCV é utilizado para o processamento de imagens mesmo...

Comment: o seu problema que você converte uma imagem para um formato não suportado com opencv. da um cv2.imread e depois usa função color2gray